# What is a decent open-source list/task management software

Tags: web-applications, open-source

I really like the application [Things](http://culturedcode.com/things/) but I need something web-based. Ideally something I can host on my server. So simply, PHP/MySQl based task-management software, which is open-source.

What would be ideal would be something where I can drag and drop to reorder the tasks.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use the minimalistic [MytinyTodo](http://www.mytinytodo.net/). It is extremely simple, so it might not be for you if you need advanced features. The web interface is quite pleasant to use.

Answer (score 0):

It might be overkill for what you want, but we're using DotProject.

http://sourceforge.net/projects/dotproject/